# How to count the number of integer points in a polyhedral?

Tags: calculus, polyhedra

Let $k, l$ be positive integers and $k_1, l_1$ non-negative integers. I have a polyhedral give by the following inequalities:
$$
A = \{(r_1,r_3,r_4,r_5): r_1+3r_4\leq l_1, -k_1 \leq r_5-r_3 \leq 0, r_4 >0, r_5 - r_3 + r_4 \leq k-k_1 \}.
$$ 
Are there some method to compute the number of integer points in the polyhedral $A$? The number of integers in $A$ is some function $a_{k,l,k_1,l_1}$ in $k,l,k_1,l_1$. Thank you very much.

Edit: maybe we need to use Ehrhart polynomial?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but picks theorem might help. Compute  the area with some other method and use that to get the number of points.

Comment: @nayrb, thank you very much. But picks theorem only works for the 2-dimensional case.